# A-Frame dynamically add objects to a-scene (JS, Html)

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm trying to add elements to the a-scene tag with innerHTML
the following code doesn't work. I would like to make a small world with Perlin Noise 3D
I don't want to write code for each block I want to render. Any idea how I can make this work?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A-Frame</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/perlin-noise-3d"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</head>
<body>


<a-scene id="scene">
</a-scene>

<script>
    $("#scene").innerHTML = '<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>'

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create elements via [`document.createElement()`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#creating-an-entity-with-createelement) and append it to the scene with [`parent.appendChild(node)`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-an-entity-with-appendchild) for them to work properly:

```js
const scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
const box = document.createElement("a-box");
box.setAttribute("color", "red");
box.setAttribute("position", "0 1 -3");
scene.appendChild(box);
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: If you want to create a world with these blocks, You'll hit performance issues - You probably should check out [instanced meshes](https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/instanced-mesh)

Comment: Also recommend checking out the docs https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-an-entity-with-appendchild